# Query for data in two tables connected by a third. Data Sometimes only on one

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join

I thought I could figure this out but I am having a lot of issues.I have 3 Tables, `Table1`, `Table2`, and `Table3`. These tables where designed by someone else and I have to work with them. They were not designed to be used the way they are used today.

The bottom line is I need to be able to enter an `Item_No`, this will always exist in `Table2`. And ***if*** the `Item_No` can also be found in `Table 3`, could be multiple times or none, and there can be times where I can find it 5 times in `Table2` and only 3 times in `Table3`. If it is in `Table3` it will also be in `Table1`.

So, using the Item_No i can find on Table2, return the Order_qty's associated with those rows. Then using the if exist getting  `Table1.ID` where `Table1.ID = Table3.ID` WHERE `Table3.Item_No = Table2.Item_No`

I came up with the following, it does not give me errors but simply stops code execution during a C# fill. I had it working for finding the `Item_No` on `Table3` and returning what it finds, I have ONLY changed this line of code since so I KNOW this is the issue.

Here is what I could come up with that is not working:

```
SELECT Table1.ID, 
       Table2.Order_Qty As [Qty of Full Order], Table2.Item_No As [Set No] 
FROM Table2 
LEFT JOIN Table3 
       ON  Table2.Item_No = Table3.Item_No 
           AND Table2.Order_No = Table3.Order_No
LEFT JOIN Table1 
       ON Table1.Order_No = Table2.Order_No 
          AND Table1.ID = Table3.ID 
WHERE Table2.Item_No = @m_strUserEnteredSeachValue
ORDER BY Table2.Order_No DESC
```

***Example Data: ***

Table 1

```
+----------+--------------+-------------------+
| Order_No | Sub_Order_No | Sub_Order_Contact |
+==========+==============+===================+
|    1     |      1       |     John Doe      |
+----------+--------------+-------------------+
|    1     |      2       |     Jane Doe      |
+----------+--------------+-------------------+
|    1     |      3       |        Foo        |
+----------+--------------+-------------------+
|    1     |      4       |        Bar        |
+----------+--------------+-------------------+
|    1     |      5       |        Foo2       |
+----------+--------------+-------------------+
```

Table 2

```
+----------+--------------+-------------------+
| Order_No |    Item_No   | Customer_Item_Name|
+==========+==============+===================+
|    1     |      1       |   1234567890      |
+----------+--------------+-------------------+
|    1     |      2       |   1234567891      |
+----------+--------------+-------------------+
|    1     |      3       |   1234567892      |
+----------+--------------+-------------------+
|    1     |      4       |   1234567893      |
+----------+--------------+-------------------+
|    1     |      5       |   1234567894      |
+----------+--------------+-------------------+
|    1     |      6       |   1234567895      |
+----------+--------------+-------------------+
|    2     |      1       |    0987654321     |
+----------+--------------+-------------------+
|    2     |      2       |    0987654322     |
+----------+--------------+-------------------+
|    2     |      3       |    0987654323     |
+----------+--------------+-------------------+
|    3     |      1       |    1234567893     |
+----------+--------------+-------------------+
```

And Table 3

```
+----------+--------------+-------------------+--------------+
| Order_No |    Item_No   | Customer_Item_Name| Sub_Order_No |
+==========+==============+===================+==============+
|    1     |      1       |   1234567890      |       1      |
+----------+--------------+-------------------+--------------+
|    1     |      2       |   1234567891      |       2      |
+----------+--------------+-------------------+--------------+
|    1     |      3       |   1234567892      |       2      |
+----------+--------------+-------------------+--------------+
|    1     |      4       |   1234567893      |       3      |
+----------+--------------+-------------------+--------------+
|    1     |      5       |   1234567894      |       4      |
+----------+--------------+-------------------+--------------+
|    1     |      6       |   1234567895      |       4      |
+----------+--------------+-------------------+--------------+
|    1     |      4       |   1234567893      |       4      |
+----------+--------------+-------------------+--------------+
```

The Result I am looking for: If I search for Item 1234567893

```
+----------+--------------+-------------------+--------------+-------------------+
| Order_No |    Item_No   | Customer_Item_Name| Sub_Order_No | Sub_Order_Contact |
+==========+==============+===================+==============+===================+
|    3     |      1       |   1234567893      |              |                   |
+----------+--------------+-------------------+--------------+-------------------+
|    1     |      4       |   1234567893      |      3       |       Foo         |
+----------+--------------+-------------------+--------------+-------------------+
|    1     |      4       |   1234567893      |      4       |       Bar         |
+----------+--------------+-------------------+--------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: So, I read your question, you explained your situation, but don't explain what is it that you want

Comment: Looks right to me, have you tried running it in Management Studio and disregarding C# and profiling?

Comment: There's no apparent reason why this shouldn't work.  Show us more of the code.

Comment: Excuse me, what is the question? Also, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Lamak I apologize I really don't work with SQL and I am having trouble even figuring out the design of what I am looking for, I was kind of relying on my Select statement to explain what I was looking for.

Comment: @zespri I am trying to get `Table1.ID, Table2.Order_Qty, Table2.Item_No` returned, where `Table1.ID = Table3.ID` where i get `Table3.ID` based on `Table3.Item_No = Table2.Item_No` and `Table3.ID` is on the same row as `Table3.Item_No`.

Comment: Can you give the tables definitions?

Comment: @zespri I can't, I think my problem is that `Table2` and `Table1` have no direct relation. I think i need something like `Left Join( Table1 inner join Table3 on Table1.ID = Table3.ID) On Table3.Item_No = Table2.Item_No` but i am lost at this point.

Comment: Why can't you? It's difficult to help when some relevant information is unknown.

Comment: @zespri As I am not the owner of it, I have no rights to share any part of the information, but i have updated my question to  point I think is more understandable.

Comment: It would help so much if you used real-world example tables instead of Table1, Table2, Table3...

Comment: @ErikE I can't It is not my data to share, but The mock tables i have supplied should be enough to get the job done.

Comment: Your tables do not match your query. You query have columns that your tables do not have. (examples are `Table1.ID` and `Table3.ID`) You can not join or query on columns that are not part of the tables.

Comment: @zespri All `ID` Columsn are equivalent to the `Sub_Order_No` my query does not work and is wrong, the mock tables I have added with sample of expected data if I could see an example that works on those then I can get the rest. I only wish I could share more. But, the example tables are the best to go off of, even if you don't answer my question but can provide a sample **Similar** query statement and explain it, would work.

Comment: What I'm saying is that I'm trying to help you to fix your query. To start off you should get rid of the invalid columns that is not in your sample data structure. This would be a start. Try rewriting your query so that it could be run on the sample data you provided. I understand that you might not get the right results from the first attempt but you at least may get something that is not giving a syntax error. It will be easier for you to figure out the way forward once you've done that.

Comment: Also looking at your data I can't tell how you intend to form columns in your expected result. Order_No and Item_No can come from 2 tables and it's not clear what are the selection criteria. How in the result Sub_Order_Contact is supposed to be derived is also a complete mystery to me.

Comment: @user2140261 I am not asking for any proprietary data. I'm asking for you to pick table names that actually have some kind of meaning to help us understand. They don't even have to be the data you're working with--just things that have similar properties. Try SalesOrder, SalesOrderHeader. Or Animal, Pet. *Anything* that has a conceptual framework we can understand rather than just "table1, 2, 3, 4".

Comment: @zespri In my expected results table `Order_No` and `Item_No` would be populated  from `Table2` but those values are identical in `Table2` and `Table3`. The selection criteria is the `Customer_Item_Name` that will be matched to the Search Term. `Sub_Order_Contact`  is matched by `Order_No` and `Sub_Order_No` between tables `Table1` and `Table3`. This is returned by a match of  Order_no and Item_No matches between `Table2` and `Table3` where `Table2.Customer_Item_Name` = `Table3.Customer_Item_Name`

Answer (score 0):

A pragmatic answer to a problem like this is to split it into a couple of queries.  Query Table #2 first, and then based on that result set, run additional queries into #1 or #3.

Another angle is to query on Table #2 and use subqueries to reach-out-there into Table #1 or Table #3 to fetch data you need.

Comment: AS in `CTE`'s i believe they are called. Or subqueries? I really don't know much about advanced sql beyond 2 tables.

Comment: I have added example data to my question in hopes of an example query that can get the correct results

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
declare @m_strUserEnteredSeachValue varchar(10) = '1234567893';
with a as
(
  select 
    Order_No, Item_No, Customer_Item_Name 
  from 
    Table2
  UNION 
  select 
    Order_No, Item_No, Customer_Item_Name 
  from 
    Table3
)
select 
  a.Order_No, 
  a.Item_No, 
  a.Customer_Item_Name,
  Table3.Sub_Order_No, 
  Table1.Sub_Order_Contact 
from 
  a
left join 
  Table3 
on 
  Table3.Order_No=a.Order_No 
  and Table3.Item_No=a.Item_No 
  and Table3.Customer_Item_Name=a.Customer_Item_Name
left join 
  Table1 
on
  Table1.Sub_Order_No = Table3.Sub_Order_No
where 
  @m_strUserEnteredSeachValue = a.Customer_Item_Name
order by 
  a.Item_No, Table3.Sub_Order_No
```

SqlFiddle demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/973d8/3

I have no idea if this is what you are trying to arrive at or not, since it's difficult to understand from you question. All I know that this query gives the dataset that you put in OP.